# How to install iOS 5 simulator with XCode 4.6.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have used xcode 4.6.3 and now I want to run my application in iOS7. How can I test my application without real device. Is it possible to install iOS 7 simulator on XCode 4.6.3 ? Please help me.

Comment: Just a small headsup, if you are planning to submit your app to the appstore you will need to build your app using Xcode 5.1 and the iOS 7 SDK. If you are running mavericks there is no way (easy way) to get the iOS 5 simulator running.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't install ios 7 simulator on Xcode 4.6.3. you have to install Xcode 5 to run your application in iOS7.

For your information new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with latest Xcode.